# Load_workbook doesn't work, no such file or directory

Tags: python, openpyxl

As the title says, load_workbook doesn't work. I tried using absolute path, but it didn't change anything and every documentation and tutorial I saw used relative path anyway and it worked perfectly. What is going on?

Yes, the file is in the right directory.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcVJB.jpg

I uploaded the image to prove that the file indeed is in the right directory, not to show my code.

Comment: no, it is not where it is searched for, else you would not get this error message.

Comment: Do I really have to repeat myself? Using absolute path does not work. The image was uploaded to prove that the directory and name are correct, but it seems like nobody believes me anyway,

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the file itself. I has to be created and saved using Excel.